# Shared definitions for with-test in Clojure

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I am struggling to see how I can define values for use in multiple tests when using with-test.  What I want to do is something like:

```
(with-test

  (defn myfunction [arg...]
    (code to test))

  (let [a (something-complex ...)
        b (something-else ...)]
    (is (= '(...) (myfunction a ....)))
    (is (= '(...) (myfunction a b ..)))
    (is (= '(...) (myfunction b ....))))
```

where i define `a` and `b` once, but use them in multiple tests (multiple assertions; this may be a single test - even that is not clear to me).

Please - how can I do this?

Comment: What you want to do should work, do you have any problems with similar code? Tip: use macroexpand to see the code generated by `with-test`.

Comment: oh!  ok, thanks - will test tomorrow.  need to sleep now...

Comment: works fine.  if you want to post that as an answer below i'll give you the vote.  also, how much can you trust this?  if i need to use macroexpand to be sure am i relying on an implementation detail?  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, the body of code after the definition given to `with-test` will get evaluated like any normal body of Clojure code, so you can use construct like `let`.

One good tip is to use `macroexpand` to look at the code generated by a macro like `with-test`. How much trust you can have in this is harder to determine. I would say that you should use your common sense to figure out what is the actual purpose of the macro you're using. Macros are powerful tools and the frontier between normally using a macro and relying on an implementation detail is much fuzzier than for a function. In this case you should be quite confident about the behavior of `with-test` by looking at the argument list, the last argument, namely `body`, implies that it accept any number of forms in the same way a function body, a `let` or a `do` would work.